# Wix uninstall not deleting registry value

Tags: wix, uninstallation

This is what I see from log during uninstall, action is null mean its not doing any action.

```
MSI (s) (00:D8) [14:54:39:091]: Component: Registry_Description; Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Null;   Client State: Local

RegistryValue Id="ExcelRegistry_Description" 
    Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\ExcelAddIn"
    Name="Description" Value="ExcelAddIn" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are installing this registry key at install?

See below links, have you setup the right action?

```
Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
```

Reference links:-
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/write_a_registry_entry.html

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrykey.html